# PrototypeJS get value of each input

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I write following function to read inputs from my `fieldset`, it works but I have no idea how to read **value** of selected this way `input`

```
$$('#split_edit div label input').each(
  function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
);
```

This is my html structure, I can't read input value using its ID because they are dynamically generated.

```
<fieldset id="split_edit">              
  <div class="top-10">
    <label>
      <span class="span-3 left">Item 1 (%)</span>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="packet_1" value="0" id="packet_3">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="top-10">
    <label>
      <span class="span-3 left">Item 1 (%)</span>
      <input type="text" class="text" name="packet_2" value="0" id="packet_7">
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

How to select value from input selected by `each` function in PrototypeJS?

I'm sorry for obvious question but I have started using PrototypeJS several hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `item.value`:

```
$$('#split_edit div label input').each(function(item) {
  console.log(item.value);
});
```

Comment: The only time this will not work is a `<select multiple>`. To read from that type of element use `item.getValue()`