# PrototypeJS input value in each() enumeration

Tags: javascript, html, performance, prototypejs

Why does the HTML/JS below return "on" values when the checkboxes aren't checked? This code is live (for now) on [tab.my](http://tab.my).

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="init" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Init</button>

<form id="domains">

  <div id="domain1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="input1" />
    <a>Domain 1</a>
  </div>

  <div id="domain2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="input2" />
    <a>Domain 2</a>
  </div>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('init').observe('click', init);

function init() {
  $('domains').select('div').each(function(domain){
    console.log(domain.select('input')[0].value);
  });
}
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805666/prototypejs-get-value-of-each-input) post, but I am trying to learn best practices when it comes to JavaScript performance and also get more fundamental. My guess was that the more you use the $ utility with the select() method and the less you use the $$ utility, the less it has to loop through. The function below returned correct values, but I need to access other elements inside each "domain div".

```
function init() {
  $('domains').getElements().each(function(input){
    console.log($F(input));
  });
}
```

I thought maybe I should use the $F utility, but the function below returned the JS error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

```
function init() {
  $('domains').select('div').each(function(domain){
    console.log($F(domain.select('input')));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $F() method requires that the element either has an ID, or has already been found and extended by Prototype. It's a useful shortcut of this construction: $(id or reference).getValue();

To do what you're after here, you could use the "double dollar" method, but if you begin it with an id, it will be near as makes no difference as fast as the "find by ID, find children" approach of $(id).select().

```
$$('#domains div input').each(function(elm){
  console.log($F(elm));
});
```

The reason why your second attempt failed is because you are using select('input'), which always returns an array as its result. If you used down('input'), that would return the input itself, which would work with $F().